# How to properly catch Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics.DeviceLostException?

Tags: c#, exception, xna, draw

I have developed a small game using C# and XNA. I ran into the problem that when I lock the screen for some time the application crashes with a:

```
Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics.DeviceLostException
```

I assumed the exception is thrown in the Draw() routine and tried to catch it by:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// This is called when the game should draw itself.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="gameTime">Provides a snapshot of timing values.</param>
    protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        try
        {
            // Draw game
            mySmallGame.Draw(gameTime);

            // TODO: Add your drawing code here
            base.Draw(gameTime);
        }
        catch (Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics.DeviceLostException)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Device lost.");
        }
    }
```

However, the exception seems not to be properly catched by that. Im will handle it later, so far only the text "Device lost." should be printed when the game is crashing.

The stack-trace is:

```
Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics.dll!Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics.GraphicsDevice.Present(tagRECT* pSource, tagRECT* pDest, HWND__* hOverride) + 0x1c6 bytes 
    Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics.dll!Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics.GraphicsDevice.Present() + 0x24 bytes 
    Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game.dll!Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GraphicsDeviceManager.Microsoft.Xna.Framework.IGraphicsDeviceManager.EndDraw() + 0x47 bytes    
    Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game.dll!Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game.EndDraw() + 0x2a bytes    
    Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game.dll!Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game.DrawFrame() + 0x13e bytes 
    Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game.dll!Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game.Tick() + 0x7a8 bytes  
    Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game.dll!Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game.HostIdle(object sender, System.EventArgs e) + 0x23 bytes  
    Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game.dll!Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GameHost.OnIdle() + 0x42 bytes 
    Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game.dll!Microsoft.Xna.Framework.WindowsGameHost.RunOneFrame() + 0x33 bytes 
    Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game.dll!Microsoft.Xna.Framework.WindowsGameHost.ApplicationIdle(object sender, System.EventArgs e) + 0x54 bytes    
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponent.FDoIdle(int grfidlef) + 0x3e bytes   
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(System.IntPtr dwComponentID, int reason, int pvLoopData) + 0x3cd bytes    
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(int reason, System.Windows.Forms.ApplicationContext context) + 0x155 bytes  
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(int reason, System.Windows.Forms.ApplicationContext context) + 0x4a bytes    
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(System.Windows.Forms.Form mainForm) + 0x31 bytes  
    Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game.dll!Microsoft.Xna.Framework.WindowsGameHost.Run() + 0x9f bytes 
    Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game.dll!Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game.RunGame(bool useBlockingRun) + 0x150 bytes    
    Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game.dll!Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game.Run() + 0x23 bytes    
>   Project_Ares.exe!Project_Ares.Program.Main(string[] args) Line 14 + 0xb bytes   C#
```

Comment: Post the stack trace. Should be able to figure out where it's failing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the stack trace. This should tell you where it's happening, and if it's even something in your code.
UPDATE: Seeing the stack trace, this is all external to your own code, and is at best fixable by configuration options. I strongly encourage you to look into MonoGame, as mentioned below

Put exception handling into your `Main` method, as that is more likely by far to be able to catch an exception - always rely first on the stack trace to tell you where something has thrown an exception, that's what it's there for! (notable exception: Threading and when exceptions get eaten by Task)

Try recompiling your game against [MonoGame](http://MonoGame.Net) instead of XNA - the latter has been discontinued for some time, and the former is still relatively active development and may or may not have already addressed this issue.